# Batch Code to increment every character by 1

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, increment

Let's say you have a text file which contains details as follows:

> ```
> User1
> ABCDEF
> ```

So what I would like to do is increment every character by 1, i.e. the output should be as follows:

> ```
> Vtfs2
> BCDEFG
> ```

I would like to store these two outputs into two different variables, i.e.:

```
Set var1=Vtfs2
Set var2=BCDEFG
```

I know there's a method using `for /f` but I haven't quite got there yet.
Here's what all I could come up with:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (Myfile.txt) do (
    set var=%%x+1
)
```

But what it does that it adds up in the form of numbers. So how do I apply this to characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is used to read and parse text and to split it into tokens, but it is not capable of converting characters into their codes (ASCII) and back.

The only way that comes to my mind to get the codes of characters in a string is using the [`CertUtil`](http://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html) utility, which provides a verb `-encodehex` to convert a text file into a hexadecimal-encoded file, and a verb `-decodehex` to do the opposite conversion. Since this relies on character codes in hexadecimal representation, and there is some maths required for the task at hand, we need to do hexadecimal to decimal conversions and vice versa; the former can be achieved by [`set /A`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and its capability of interpreting hexadecimal numbers when being prefixed with `0x`; the latter can be accomplished using an undocumented built-in variable called [`=ExitCode`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html), which contains the hexadecimal representation of the latest [exit code](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html), which in turn can be set by [`cmd`](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)`/C`[`exit`](http://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)`%NUMBER%`, where `%NUMBER%` is the decimal exit code (exit code and `ErrorLevel` are not always the same, but in our situation they are).

So let us put all these things together now:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set /A "_MIN=0x20" & rem // (minimal character code to regard for rotation)
set /A "_MAX=0x7F" & rem // (maximal character code to regard for rotation)
set "_TMP=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (path to temporary file)

rem // Convert provided rotation offset parameter to number:
set "OFFSET=%~3"
set /A "OFFSET+=0"
rem // Convert input text file to temporary hexadecimal-encoded file:
> nul CertUtil -encodehex "%~1" "%_TMP%" || (
    >&2 echo The system cannot find the file specified.
    exit /B 1
)
rem // Read temporary hexadecimal-encoded file, then clear it:
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=  " %%K in ('type "%_TMP%" ^& ^> "%_TMP%" rem/') do (
    rem // Get line with the preceding position number removed:
    set "NEW= " & set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Iterate through all character codes of the current line:
    for %%K in (!LINE:~^,48!) do (
        rem // Retrieve a single character code as decimal number:
        set /A "CODE=0x%%K"
        rem // Check whether character code is in applicable range:
        if !CODE! GEQ %_MIN% if !CODE! LEQ %_MAX% (
            rem /* Perform rotation by adding the given offset;
            rem    adapt result if predefined range is left: */
            set /A "CODE+=OFFSET%%(1+_MAX)"
            if !CODE! LSS %_MIN% set /A "CODE+=1+_MAX-_MIN"
            if !CODE! GTR %_MAX% set /A "CODE-=1+_MAX-_MIN"
        )
        rem /* Convert rotated character code to hexadecimal number,
        rem    collect the character codes in a single line: */
        cmd /C exit !CODE!
        set "NEW=!NEW!!=ExitCode:~-2! "
    )
    rem // Write line of collected character codes to temporary file:
    >> "%_TMP%" echo(!NEW:~1,-1!
    endlocal
)
rem // Convert temporary hexadecimal-encoded file to output text file:
> nul CertUtil -f -decodehex "%_TMP%" "%~2" || (
    >&2 echo The system cannot find the path specified.
    exit /B 1
)
rem // Clean up temporary file:
del "%_TMP%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

This script -- let us call it `rotate-chars.bat` -- expects three command line arguments: the path to the input text file, the path to the output text file (which might be the same as the input file to modify it directly) and the number by which the character codes are to be rotated (according to your question this should be set to `+1`). So when calling the script with the following command line...:

```
rotate-chars.bat "test.txt" "test_NEW.txt" +1
```

...and having the following content of `test.txt`...:

> ```
> User1
> ABCDEF
> ```

..., a temporary file holds the following content immediately after the first execution of `CertUtil` within the script:

> ```
> 0000  55 73 65 72 31 0d 0a 41  42 43 44 45 46 0d 0a      User1..ABCDEF..
> ```

After the `for /F` loop being executed, the temporary file contains:

> ```
> 56 74 66 73 32 0D 0A 42 43 44 45 46 47 0D 0A
> ```

You can see that every character code has been increased by one, except those outside of the range given in the top section of the script (so `0x20` to `0x7F`; any codes outside are not touched). The initial position (`0000`) and the final text columns are omitted as they are not needed for reverse conversion.

After that upon the second execution of `CertUtil`, the returned output file `test_NEW.txt` is going to contain the following data:

> ```
> Vtfs2
> BCDEFG
> ```

Note that if a character code became shifted out of the given range at one bound, for instance `0x7E` + `5` = `0x83` with the bounds `0x20` and `0x7F`, it was moved to the opposite end, like `0x23` (= `0x83` - (`0x7F` + 1) + `0x20`); that is why the term "rotation" is used.

---

To store the first two lines of the resulting text file into variables, you could do the following:

```
< "test_NEW.txt" (
    set /P var1=""
    set /P var2=""
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Answer. I assumed the answer would be easy. But it appears to be very complex. You've really got lot of brains.I will go through all of this and let you know. Thanks a lot again for your efforts.